# can't launch windows slave agent (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins

I set my master URL to : http://[master_ip]:8080
I configured the windows slave machine as follows:
[slave_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6If5.jpg)

Now I'm trying to launch the slave using the agent.jar by running the command:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://[master_ip]:8080/computer/slave_node/slave-agent.jnlp -workDir "C:\Jenkins"
```

and it can't connect for some reason:

> Failing to obtain
>   http://[master_ip]:8080/computer/slave_node/slave-agent.jnlp
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:490)
>           at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:322)
>           at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:283) Waiting 10 seconds before retry

I followed a million tutorials, repeated the same steps over and over...Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the Jenkins master form the slave, there could be some connectivity issue, if there is no connectivity issue, try launching the windows slave from the browser

Comment: thanks for your reply!.. This is the issue..there is no connectivity for some reason..it means I can't access the master account from the slave's browser. can't figure out what is missing.